# HTML Semantics: Should the icon to trigger the menu on a responsive page be included in the nav?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics, semantic-markup

Lets compare the following three code examples:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="trigger.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Example 1

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#"><img src="trigger.png"></a>
</nav>
```

Example 2

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<a href="#"><img src="trigger.png"></a>
```

Example 3

Regarding semantics, which one is the most precise - should the menu trigger be included in the list inside `nav`, inside `nav` but outside the list or even outside `nav`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd prefer:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button title="Show / Hide menu"><img src="trigger.png" alt="Show / Hide menu"></button>
</nav>
```

(note the landmark role and use of a button)
because the trigger will be found by Assistive Technologies (screen readers mainly but not only them) *inside* the element where they expect to find the main navigation of a website.

- `[role="navigation"]` will help browsers ant ATs to find without any doubt the navigation. Other landmark roles are banner, contentinfo, search, main, complementary (and other less important to current use)
- [`button` should be used](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201104/make_links_focusable_or_use_real_buttons/) instead of link element whenever clicking on the 'link' doesn't jump to another page, anchor and/or if the `href` attribut has a value of `#`)

Comment: Thats quite interesting! I just read the important parts of the spec again. An input element with `type="button"` is defined as "a button with no default behavior". So one could say that input with `type="button"` is the correct element to use, as the "default behavior" (or even the whole button) is created via JS. But there is also the `<button>` element, which is said to "do nothing" if its not a submit or reset button. Do you have any opinion on that, what markup should I use to create the button? Why did you favor `<button>` over and input with `type="button"` in the example?

Comment: Mainly for design reasons: I'll have to insert an image or a character of a font-icon and I can put text and elements between opening and closing tags while `input` doesn't have such freedom. Otherwise I *believe* there's no semantic difference delivered to accessibility API: it's "here is a button" in both cases (I didn't verify myself)

Comment: Its true, I also can't find any real semantic differences between the two types of button. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

A bit more belt and braces, but I would suggest:

```
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="navHeading">
<h2 class="at" id="navHeading">Main menu</h2>

<button aria-haspopup="true"><img src="trigger.png" alt="Show menu"></button>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

A few accessibility things:

- `H2`, hidden from view (the `.at` class should hide it off-screen).
- `role` on the `nav`, as that is more robust (more things will understand that).
- `aria-labelledby`, combined with the `ID` will label the navigation.
- `aria-haspopup` indicates there is a pop-up or new thing being shown.

I'd go with `button` for the show/hide mechanism because it doesn't take you anywhere, it controls something on the page. Top or bottom probably doesn't make much difference, but I'm used to controls for show/hide elements being at the start.

However, I would make sure that when selected the keyboard focus gets placed on the first link.

Also, don't forget that the button should have content, so the image needs alt text.

Comment: Right, control before the shown/hidden items avoids the necessity of managing focus!